# Flutter typeAhead error :queryrow is not asubtype of string

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Im trying to display suggestion in a textfield using typeahead but i receive an error"queryro is not a subtype of string"

```
Future<List<dynamic>> _getSuggestions(String query) {
return OrderProvider.db.rawQuery(
    "select TypeOfProduct from Items where TypeOfProduct = ?", [query]);
```

}
**This is the  code I use to fetch data from database **

```
TypeAheadFormField(
              textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                controller: this._typeController,
                autocorrect: true,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Product Name"),
              ),
              suggestionsCallback: (suggestion) async {
                return _getSuggestions(suggestion);
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(suggestion),
                );
              },
              onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                this._typeController.text = suggestion;
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OrderProvider.db.rawQuery(
    "select TypeOfProduct from Items where TypeOfProduct = ?", [query]);
```

This return a `List<Map>` (If you're using sqfLite) and suggestionsCallback will pass that List to the itemBuilder, but itemBuilder is using those suggestions to build a Text Widget (and Text expects something of type `String`, not of type `Map`). so you can reduce the Map before using return in the `_getSuggestions(String query)` method to return a List or do something like this

```
itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {//suggestion is of type Map because thats what you returned
   return ListTile(
     title: Text(suggestion['product']), //or whatever the key name is
   );
},
```